# How to write a regular expression to search for Credit Card Number in a Hex stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, credit-card

I need help with suggestions on how to search for a Credit Card number in a Hex using regular expression?  I'm not a programmer, but I'm learning as I go along and find examples and dissecting them.

So far I have found regular expressions that matche 13-16 digits in ASCII,  `\b(?:\d[ -]*?){13,16}\b` and the following `(?:3[4|7]\d{2})(?:[ ,-]?(?:\d{5}(?:\d{1})?)){2}|(?:4\d{3})(?:[ ,-]?(?:\d{4})){3}|(?:5[1-5]\d{2})(?:[ ,-]?(?:\d{4})){3}|(?:6011)(?:[ ,-]?(?:\d{4})){3}` to match all the major issuers in one sweep; however I'm not sure how to match the hex equvalent.  The reason I'm looking to do this is to protect queries that contain Credit Cards in either stored ore queried in ASCII, EBCDIC, or integer.  I have a function using binary scan that will allow me to take the payload and covert to Hex in TCL and another means to dump the payload in Hex to Node.js.

Comment: If you want answers you should give more details of the actual data. For example, are the numbers all hex with no spaces? with dashes? Spaces or dashes? Hex formatted as in 'FF' or '0xFF'? Type out a made up example of what needs to be converted.

Comment: Since you are asking to search only (as the question) why can't you just use a simple regex like this for hex: `(?:3[0-9]){4}-?(?:3[0-9]){4}-?(?:3[0-9]){4}-?(?:3[0-9]){4}`   ?